# Can pyCharm recognized two package with same name?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

There are 2 `us` packages under Project1 and Project2, and I mark the two src directory as sources root.

But it seems pyCharm can't recognized the Runner1 package. Why? How should I configure the project?

Comment: `Namespace packages` came to my mind https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/, but I'm not familiar with them.